Google React Picker with nextjs
I'm trying to open Google Picker automatically in some conditions, but now it always fails. I'm not sure I understand why. Ideally, when the page ends the loading, Google Picker should open when isCopiedData is true.
Let me share my component:
'use client'

 ...

export default function Select({ user, automationId, gdoc_id, gdoc_name, gdoc_url, isCopiedData, templateName }) {

const [openPicker, authResponse] = useDrivePicker();
const [document, setDocument] = useState('');
const [variable, setVariable] = useState([]);
const router = useRouter();

useEffect(() => {
    if (isCopiedData) {
        console.log('isCopiedData', isCopiedData);
         searchFile();

         async function fetchData() {
            setTimeout(() => {
                searchFile();
            }, 1000);
         }

         fetchData();
    }
}, [isCopiedData]);

const searchFile = async () => {
    try {

        openPicker({
            clientId: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_API}`,
            developerKey: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_DEVELOPER_API}`,
            viewId: "DOCS",
            token: user.access_token,
            showUploadView: true,
            showUploadFolders: true,
            multiselect: true,
            appId: 'test',
            disableDefaultView: true,
            customViews: isCopiedData ? [sharedDocsView, ownedDocsView] : [defaultView, sharedDocsView, ownedDocsView],
            callbackFunction: async (data) => {
                if (data.action === 'cancel') {
                    console.log('User clicked cancel/close button')
                } else if (data.action === 'picked') {
                 ...

                }
            },
        })

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};

 ...
return (...)

What am I doing wrong?
